# Docker COPY doesn't seem to take in changes to files

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I use Gitlab CI to build and deploy my docker compose file to the docker host.

Where I see a weird issue with the `COPY` command where I don't see any new changes done to the files copied to the docker container.

```
#Copy code files to containers code directory
COPY ./src/pyvol ./src/pyvol   # directory with utility libraries
COPY ./src/setup_* ./src/      # entrypoint scripts
```

The command works fine when the containers are deleted and recreated, I wouldn't want to do that as its not a good way to have continuous integration.

Under the `gitlab-ci.yml` the below are configured

```
.build_image_config:
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache --pull
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml push

.deploy_config:
  script:
    - docker -H $DOCKER_HOST --tlsverify stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml $STACK_NAME  --resolve-image always
```

Would I need to explicitly provide any other parameters while build and deploy to instruct the CI to take in the recent changed files.

Comment: That looks pretty similar to my gitlab pipelines. Which job is failing to notice the changes: if the build step triggers and pushes an image, then you know the registry has a new instance of the image.  In which case the stack deploy should notice the the image hash - unless you are seeing a message there about "image hash could not be verified".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands instead:

```
docker-compose up -d --build --no-cache
```

In docker compose version 2:

```
docker compose up -d --build --force-recreate
```